# How to stop all child chromium instances related to this specific parent node.js server?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, child-process

I am running node js application in the background in ubuntu server using below command

> nohup node app.js > /dev/null &

This application launches headerless chrome using puppeteer module.

TO stop server we are using below commands..

> ps -aux | grep node
>
> kill -9 pid

The above commands stoping the main node server but not the child processes that are running chromium instances(puppeteer).
How to stop all child chromium instances related to this specific parent node.js server?

Answer (score 0):

Puppeteer API has [`browser.close()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#browserclose) method to shutdown Chromium and all of its pages (if any were opened). You are able to create a function which will take care of the browser, similar to ...

```js
/**
* Closes browser instance
* @function
*/
export async function shutdownBrowser() {
    if (browser) {
        logger.info({ "pid": browser.process().pid }, "Trying to shutdown browser.");
        await browser.close();
    }
}
```

After you would call this function when NodeJS process is about to exit, similar to ...

```js
// clan up listenners
process.on('beforeExit', () => router.shutdownBrowser());
process.on('uncaughtException', () => router.shutdownBrowser());

const termSignals: NodeJS.Signals[] = ['SIGHUP', 'SIGINT', 'SIGQUIT', 'SIGILL', 
'SIGTRAP', 'SIGABRT',
'SIGBUS', 'SIGFPE', 'SIGUSR1', 'SIGSEGV', 'SIGUSR2', 'SIGTERM'];
termSignals.forEach((eventType) => {
    process.on(eventType, () => router.shutdownBrowser());
});
```

To be honest all of it is overkill if you would use NodeJS management software, for example [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/). When you would issue command to `stop` your NodeJS server to PM2 it will gracefully shutdown all the child processes and you browser will be gone, without single line of coding.